# How to match with Regex a newline that before does not have a pattern

Tags: regex

There's a way to match from a text with a regex a newline that before does not have a specific patter?

An example could be a newline that not has the end tag `</u>`

So if there's the string

```
caaaaa
aaa
<u>refnkrnkfenr</u>
rllllrmlef
rhgfvhr
hbgfdsa
```

has to match 1st 2nd 4th 5th 6th line

The try with a negative lookahead `/(?!\<\/u\>)(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g` does not works and I don't know why.

What's the correct way to have the correct match?

Comment: Do you mean `(?<!\<\/u\>)(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\Z)` ? https://regex101.com/r/UIr34J/1

Comment: Andrej Kesely - *Do you mean `(?<!\<\/u\>)(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\Z)`?* regex101.com/r/UIr34J/1 YESSS It's exactly what I need. (Your regex101 example returns 'A critical error occurred', but it's exactly what I need). Tnx. If u want answer to the question you can catch the upvote and the correct answer

Comment: I've added an answer, glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?<!\<\/u\>)(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\Z)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/UIr34J/1)

Note the negative look-behind `(?<!...)` instead of `(?!...)`. Also I've added `\Z` to catch end of file.

Comment: It's exactly what I need. I don't understand english very well, so tnx to u now the difference between the negative look-behind `(?<!...)` and the look-ahead `(?!...)` it's more comprensible. The demo not working it's a little detail. Your note are divines. You earned rightly your award. Still now the upvote is impossible for me. As soon as I have the reputation it will be yours. Tnx.